# Why my HTML form tries to execute PHP but there's no PHP in index.html?

Tags: html

```
   <div class="row contact__main">
        <div class="col-eight tab-full contact__form">
            <form name="contactForm" id="contactForm" method="post" action="https://formspree.io/censored@gmail.com">
                <fieldset>

                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactName" type="text" id="contactName" placeholder="Name" value="" minlength="2" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactEmail" type="email" id="contactEmail" placeholder="Email" value="" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <input name="contactSubject" type="text" id="contactSubject" placeholder="Subject" value="" class="full-width">
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <textarea name="contactMessage" id="contactMessage" placeholder="message" rows="10" cols="50" required="" aria-required="true" class="full-width"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <button class="full-width btn--primary">Submit</button>
                    <div class="submit-loader">
                        <div class="text-loader">Sending...</div>
                        <div class="s-loader">
                            <div class="bounce1"></div>
                            <div class="bounce2"></div>
                            <div class="bounce3"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>

            <!-- contact-warning -->
            <div class="message-warning">
                Something went wrong. Please try again.
            </div> 

            <!-- contact-success -->
            <div class="message-success">
                Your message was sent, thank you!<br>
            </div>
```

This is my website in question: [https://xpmai.tumblr.com/test](https://web.archive.org/web/20171230125144/https://xpmai.tumblr.com/test)

According to what I see in Chrome Browser Console, the form tries to execute PHP from GitHub, but GitHub doesn't support PHP. So it failed. But the weird thing is, it's just a HTML form. The entire **[index.html](https://github.com/XPMai/XP-HOLA-vCard/blob/617827801761dcfe8a57d3de3c7d14b4a7d0fae8/index.html#L757)** doesn't have a single PHP code. So how can I resolve this??

**Edit:** To be more specific and plain, I have an HTML form. When I try to submit the form, it says PHP error. `jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST https://xpmai.tumblr.com/inc/sendEmail.php 404 ()` But in that code above, I can't figure out how to resolve it. How to like disable the PHP and make it do the **POST** action above?

Comment: pls add your console logs in here. I cant see anything php related on your website.

Comment: @JohannesMerz `jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST https://xpmai.tumblr.com/inc/sendEmail.php 404 ()`

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you see? When doing what? Loading the page, submitting the form...?

Comment: There’s obviously more than what you posted, including some JS...

Comment: view-source:https://rawgit.com/XPMai/XP-HOLA-vCard/master/js/main.js  ajax contact form is in question. And, of course, php is needed for form processing. Since there is no php script on provided address, you got 404 error.

Comment: oh cool, thanks so much @sinisake! You should post that as answer. I really didn't know external factors matter. I only know HTML, and based on the code itself, it seems perfect.